# <iframe not working in Edge, but works in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: iframe, microsoft-edge

I have a basic iframe embedding HTML content. I applied a workaround to get it to work in IE11, but doesn't work in Edge. Works great in Chrome and FireFox. Half of my users are on Edge...

```
<iframe
    title="My iframe should work"
    class="large"
    id="my-slide-should-work"
    src="javascript: window.frameElement.getAttribute('srcdoc');" // this fixed it for IE11
    scrolling="no"
    srcdoc='<!DOCTYPE html><html>all the goodness</html>'>
</iframe>
```

Edge just shows a blank space, errors out about the JS

```
SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getAttribute' of undefined or null reference
javascript: window.frameElement.getAttribute('srcdoc'); (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **window.frameElement** is NULL and because of that it is not able to get 'srcdoc' using **getAttribute**.

Below can be the possible reason why it is Null.

> If the window isn't embedded into another document, or if the document
>   into which it's embedded has a different origin (such as having been
>   located from a different domain), this is null.

So you can try to check for the above mentioned criteria and I suggest you to create a script segment and try to check whether **window.frameElement** is Null or not. If it is not null than try use **GetAttribute** before assign its value to IFrame src.

Another thing you need to notice that **srcdoc** attribute is not supported in MS Edge. So MS Edge will not have any effect of that attribute.

References:

(1) [Window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement)

(2) [<'iframe'>: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)